# Separate the Data from Resources

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am creating array and separate its component in ListBoxes 1 and 2;
The code is taking the data from a text file (data1.txt) then split;
The file contents is as below:

```
Name1111xx,Phone1111yy
Name2222xx,Phone2222yy
Name3333xx,Phone3333yy
Name4444xx,Phone4444yy
Name5555xx,Phone5555yy
Name6666xx,Phone6666yy
Name7777xx,Phone7777yy
Name8888xx,Phone8888yy
Name9999xx,Phone9999yy
```

The code will put names in `textbox1` and phones in `textbox2`;
Now I moved the data1.txt to the Solution Resources; 
I tried to do the same separation but I couldn't; it might be simple code??
I code get it and insert it into richtextbox1;

My code is below:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines("Data1.txt")
            Dim AllData = line.Split(","c)
            Dim Name = AllData(0)
            Dim Phone = AllData(1)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Name)
            ListBox2.Items.Add(Phone)
        Next
        TextBox1.Text = "Data2"
        Dim objReader As String = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(TextBox1.Text)
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(objReader)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: what error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the path for your textfile. In your code,

```
For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines("Data1.txt")
```

`Data1.txt` should be the `path` of that file. You said you have changed its location to the resources folder so probably that's where you'll get your `path`.

Comment: I have NO problem with opening Data1.txt and its path; the question is about Data2.txt in the resources; I was successful in opening it but not sure how to show separate names in textbox1 and phones in textbox2 as per my example above.